# Displaying category images on homepage in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am attemtping - and failing - to display the category image (thumbnail) on my WordPress homepage. Here is my code:-

```
    <?php $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
           $cat_id = get_cat_ID( single_cat_title(null, false) );
           query_posts( "cat=$cat_id&paged=$paged&posts_per_page=7" );
           $i=1;
           if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post();
    ?>


            <div class="latest_cat_post col-md-3">

                <div class="news_thumb">

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                    <?php if ( has_category_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_category_thumbnail();
                        } else { ?>
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/default-featured.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                    <?php } ?>
                    </a>

                    <div class="cat_name"><?php the_category('&bull;'); ?></div>
                </div>
```

However, this fails, citing "Fatal error: Call to undefined function has_category_thumbnail()", so I assume this function does not exist, but strangely, has_post_thumbnail() does, so I assumed this would be the case for categories too - perhaps I am wrong.

Can anyone give me 2 minutes of their day to fix this problem? I don't want to use a plugin, when it *should* be relatively straightforward to do. Thanks!

Comment: There are no category (taxonomy) thumnails in Wordpress. Did you install a plugin like the following? https://wordpress.org/plugins/category-thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress you don't have category thumbnails, but you can try use a plugin. Try [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/).

Assuming you will have the category ID, you have to do something like this:

```
$images = get_option('taxonomy_image_plugin');
$cat_id = $category->term_taxonomy_id;
if( array_key_exists( $cat_id, $images ) ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $images[$cat_id] );
}
```

For more information you can visit this [related question/answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95889/show-thumbnail-for-category).